# Can't download with WebClient() on Windows XP?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

When I run my program on a Windows 8.1 machine, I can download a file with

```
webClient.DownloadFileAsync(URL, location);
```

But when I run same program on a Windows XP machine with .NET3.5 installed, I get this error:

> system.net.webexception. The remote server returned en error (404). Not found".

This error is caught in the `Completed` event of my `WebClient` ((e.Error!= null)), but not in the catch block of `webClient.DownloadFileAsync(URL, location)`.

Comment: The server returning 404 means that you have something environmentally different on the non-functional system. Proxy? DNS issues? You should check the log on the server to see if it's requesting the same URI

Comment: If you try to download that file from a browser on the XP machine, does it work?